# What is the "best practice" for resizing text with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, usability, accessibility

What is the "best practice" (accessibility/usability-wise) for resizing text with Javascript?

My current solution is that for when the user clicks the resize link it adds an extra class to the body tag.

It also sets a cookie and then when the page is loaded - onLoad() - it reads the cookie and reapplys the body class tag again if needs be.

The only thing not ideal is that it loads then applys - the previous solution was to edit the CSS file before the page loaded but that threw up security warnings if the CSS file was in a different directory.

So, essentially is my solution reasonable or is there a better way?

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution sounds fine, with one addition: you can read the cookie as the page loads and add the class to the body element while the markup is generated. Most server-side languages support this: PHP, JSP, RoR etc.
Other than that, you have a solid solution.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the "best practice"
>   (accessibility/usability-wise) for
>   resizing text with Javascript?

Best practise is "Don't".

Specify the font size in relative units and let the native browser controls change it if the user wishes.

Attempts to duplicate this functionality rarely give the font sizes that users need (and usually end up offering a choice atomic, microscopic and tiny). Yes, some users need 72pt text (or larger).

The built in browser controls work on most, if not all, sites. You don't need to use up canvas real estate duplicating them.

Comment: I think you're wrongly assuming that beginner users know that they can resize text from within the browser itself.

Also, by changing the font-size on the body element to a relative unit, you're not breaking any browser functionality.

Furthermore, only Internet Explorer has trouble with resizing pixel-sized text. So even if he used pixels, it would still be usable in most modern browsers.

Comment: I didn't really want to get into a discussion about whether it in of itself is a best practice but what would be the best practice of doing it via javascript.

Is it really that bad to duplicate functionality?

Comment: It wastes developers time, fills up the screen with more choices for the user, and gives them an alternative way of doing something they can already do better. If users need different sized text, then they will have the same need for most other websites - and will have learned how to use their browser. This isn't a problem that websites need to solve - they just need to make sure their layout doesn't break when the user resizes the text.

Answer (score 0):

### Adding a CSS style to HTML via JavaScript

I think your suggestion is an excellent way of doing it.

It means you have the flexibility of being able to add the CSS class to any sub element rather than the body so that you can change the text size of a specific element if you so desire.

Reading the cookie on page load

To get around the issue you describe I would look for the cookie in your server side language (php/asp/ruby etc) and display the content as specified by the cookie on page load.

In PHP your CSS class definition may look like this:

```
echo '<div class=\"'.($_COOKIE['text_size']!='' ? $_COOKIE['text_size'] : 'normal'). '\">';
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the "best practice" (accessibility/usability-wise) for resizing text with Javascript?

"Web Accessibility Gone Wild" [sums it up](http://www.webaim.org/articles/gonewild/#options) quite nicely imho:

> If your default font size may be too small for site visitors, then make it an adequate size.

and,

> All browsers allow the sizing or scaling of the page content - why duplicate this browser functionality?

Also, [Care With Font Size](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/font-size):

> The problem here is a basic usability and accessibility issue: a good design should look good without requiring the user to enlarge or reduce the text size.

However, if you have a *valid* reason - feel free to ignore this.

Comment: Your answer gave me this idea: what if you'd use the metrics on how your users prefer the text-size to make design adjustments?

Comment: @Dan: sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say, could you please clarify? Do you mean something like this: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=463591?